# Cannot read the xml file using simplexml_load_file ();

Tags: php, xml, api

I am having a problem reading data from an online xml file, when I use the simplexml_load_file () function; I encountered an error.
My code PHP:

```
$url = "https://www.bidv.com.vn/ServicesBIDV/ExchangeRateServlet";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
echo '</pre>';
```

input eror

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(https://www.bidv.com.vn/ServicesBIDV/ExchangeRateServlet): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in D:\All In One\xammp\htdocs\ty_gia_api\index.php on line 12
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://www.bidv.com.vn/ServicesBIDV/ExchangeRateServlet" in D:\All In One\xammp\htdocs\ty_gia_api\index.php on line 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get contents from URL like:

```
$url = "https://www.bidv.com.vn/ServicesBIDV/ExchangeRateServlet";
$xml = simplexml_load_string(shell_exec("curl -k '$url'"));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
echo '</pre>';
```

I see the page you try to get is not XML, its JSON.
This will work:

```
$url = 'https://www.bidv.com.vn/ServicesBIDV/ExchangeRateServlet';
$data = json_decode(shell_exec("curl -k '$url'"), 1);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: How is either of these going to solve a 403 error on the remote server?

Comment: 403 means forbidden, you need to login maybe?

Comment: I think there is a problem with the content link that prevents me from reading the content, but I have no workaround yet